# node js, read a specific column from csv file and convert it to an array to be used in other function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv

I am trying to get the basic grasp of parsing a CSV file with node js.

I wrote a simple function to get the last character (in my case it is always a number) of every string in an array and show me the biggest number:

```js
var ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS = ["email_1", "email_22"]


function GET_NUMBER() {
    let MAXIMAL_NUMBER;
    for (let i = 0; i < ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS.length; i += 1) {
        if (MAXIMAL_NUMBER == null || MAXIMAL_NUMBER == undefined || MAXIMAL_NUMBER < (ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS[i].slice(-1))) {
            MAXIMAL_NUMBER = (ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS[i].slice(-1))
        }
    }
    return MAXIMAL_NUMBER;
}


let MAXIMAL_NUMBER_FINAL = GET_NUMBER();
console.log(MAXIMAL_NUMBER_FINAL);
```

this piece of code works as expected:

```sh
> node index.js
> 2
```

However what I am trying to do know is to parse a csv file and extract only col2 of this file and store the values in my variable `var ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS;` so it behaves as if I declared the array this way: `var ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS = ["email_1", "email_2"]`.

I manage to successfully parse the whole csv file, but when I am trying to use only a certain column I always fail.

Could you please show me how to use only a certain column from a CSV file and store it as an array so I can use it in my `GET_NUMBER` function? I know it should be possible by either index or name, but it just simply does not work for me.

Example of the csv:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
aaa1,aaa_1,aaa3,aaa4
bbb1,bbb_2,bbb3,bbb4
ccc1,ccc_3,ccc3,ccc4
```

For this I am using a csv package (`npm install csv`)

Thanks

Edit

With Barkaas help I have this:

```js
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync'); //include
const fs = require("fs");

//loading data from the file
var global_data = fs.readFileSync("data.csv").toString();

//the dataset
const input = global_data;

//calling the npm package and save to records
const records = parse(input, {
  columns: true,
  skip_empty_lines: true
});

//map the output from csv-parse to the column
const column_two = records.map(rec => rec["col2"]);

//assing the values to another variable used in my function
var ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS = column_two//["aaa_1", "bbb_4444444", "ccc_3333333"]

//function to return the highest number in every string
function GET_NUMBER() {
    let MAXIMAL_NUMBER;
    for (let i = 0; i < ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS.length; i += 1) {
        let n = ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS[i].lastIndexOf('_');
        let result = ARRAY_OF_ALL_EMAILS[i].substring(n + 1);
        if (MAXIMAL_NUMBER == null || MAXIMAL_NUMBER == undefined || MAXIMAL_NUMBER < result) {
            MAXIMAL_NUMBER = result
        }
    }
    return MAXIMAL_NUMBER;
}

//print the highest number from every string
let MAXIMAL_NUMBER_FINAL = GET_NUMBER();
console.log(MAXIMAL_NUMBER_FINAL);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted the example from https://csv.js.org/parse/api/sync/ with your example dataset. The following code is untested.

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync'); //include

//the dataset
const input = `
col1,col2,col3,col4
aaa1,aaa_1,aaa3,aaa4
bbb1,bbb_2,bbb3,bbb4
ccc1,ccc_3,ccc3,ccc4
`;

//calling the npm package and save to records
const records = parse(input, {
  columns: true,
  skip_empty_lines: true
});
//map the output from csv-parse to the column
const column_two = records.map(rec => rec["col2"]);
```

Comment: thank you, I implemented it to my code and it works, for the const variable I use this way to get the data: `fs.readFileSync("data.csv").toString();` Is this the correct way? It is working for me, but I am not sure if this is how am I supposed to do that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do that. The other ways to implement this, is to use the async functions. But this should only affect performance.

Comment: Yes, I marked it as resolved, thank you very much :-)